'user_multi_procs=True' with seleniumbase
I am writing an application in python which is currently using undetected-chromedriver for a web bot. I am trying to switch to seleniumbase, by creating a 'Driver' object.
My driver at the moment looks like this:
driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, user_multi_procs=True, headless=True)

I have looked at the docs and I am unsure how to pass the argument 'user_multi_procs=True' into the seleniumbase.Driver object. How do I do this?

Maybe check here: https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/uc_mode/#uc-mode  (Looks like it has UC already built-in)

This works fine so far: driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=True, uc_subprocess=True), I just don't know how to pass the 'user_multi_procs' argument since I cannot see any reference to it in the seleniumbase Driver docs.
